# Except DAX query (or other)

Tags: powerbi, dax, except

I am building a report in Power BI, and I want to compare individuals who have an account vs. those who are actively using the account, but I can't figure out the DAX query I need, or at least am not getting the syntax right.

I have two tables - one that includes subscription data (user, applicationID, start date, end date) and one that includes usage data (user, applicationID, usage date)

I need the subset of users who have a specific applicationID but haven't used it (within a time frame set by a filter, and another filter for applicationID)

I think I need some combination of Except(evaluate(if(users with application)),(users with usage)) but I can't get the syntax right.  When I try to reference a table/column, the column name is grayed out, so the formula won't return any results.

This is a simplified model of the entire data set I'm working with, but I have one table with user subscription data and one with usage data:

Subscription data:
[Subscriptiondata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6zra.png)
Usage data:
[Usagedata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMao.png)
The fields that joins them are:
Subscription "Sub_User_TIMSS_id" = Usage "app_user"
Subscription "mti_role_name" = Usage "app_name"

The usage table indicates each time that a specific user accesses a specific app

The end goal of this report is to identify individuals who have a subscription to an app but have not used it in a specified time period.

An example of a MySQL query that would satisfy this need is for one specific app is:

```
SELECT Subscription_App.Sub_User_TIMSS_id,
   Subscription_App.App_id,
   Subscription_App.Sub_Start_Date,
   Subscription_App.Sub_End_Date,
   Subscription_App.mti_role_name
FROM MTI.Subscription_App Subscription_App
WHERE (Subscription_App.mti_role_name = 'ForeignTrade')                
AND     (Subscription_App.Sub_User_TIMSS_id NOT IN 
            (
            SELECT app_usage.app_user
            FROM `usage`.app_usage app_usage
            WHERE (app_usage.app_name = 'ForeignTrade')
            ))
```

However, I can't simply use a query as my data source in Power BI because I want the user of the report to be able to specify an app and a time frame - the filter would indicate the parameters of the query as opposed to the query itself specifying the app name (in the example above, the query would represent if the user selected the app name Foreign Trade and all time in the filters).  Someone may have used the app within the last year but not within the last month - or they may have used one app but not another, so the end result needs to factor this in.

I'm not experienced enough in DAX to figure out how to accomplish this yet.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, your existing code, and an example of what your desired results look like?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask